# Dax Measure - Count How Many time Employee row has specific value

Tags: powerbi, dax, powerpivot

I have  a data set that looks like this;

```
EmpNumber| Symbole
122144| 9101
122144| 2101
122144| 9101
122144| 9101
144856| 2101
144856| 9101
```

I want to check for each Employee in my "PaymentsPrevMonthOnly" table (144856 & 122144) how many rows they have with the text value in Symbole column "9101" the means "Hourly Rate Component" symbole in my table.
I have a part of formula, but it returns me an error.

Here is my DAX formula:

```
Hourly Rate Component Duplicate:=

var symbole= "9101"
var Emp = PaymentsPrevMonthOnly[EmpNumber]
return

CALCULATE(
    COUNTROWS(PaymentsPrevMonthOnly),
    PaymentsPrevMonthOnly[Symbole]= symbole && PaymentsPrevMonthOnly[EmpNumber]=Emp
)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the simplest measure definition to count the number of rows where Symbole = "9101".

```
Hourly Rate Component Duplicate =
CALCULATE (
    COUNTROWS ( PaymentsPrevMonthOnly ),
    PaymentsPrevMonthOnly[Symbole] = "9101"
)
```

You don't need to specifically filter by Employee in the measure definition. When you add Employee in the visual, Power BI automatically calculate it for each Employee.

[image: Visual]

This line should be where you are getting the error:

```
var Emp = PaymentsPrevMonthOnly[EmpNumber]
```

This expression needs a "row context" for PaymentsPrevMonthOnly table in order to be a valid DAX expression which returns a scalar value. However, a measure does not have a row context, unless it has some iterator function (e.g. SUMX, FILTER).